# Flash Player 13.0 debugger for Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: flash, flash-cc

I'm trying to add Flash Player 13.0 to the target list on Flash Professional CC (Windows 7, 64 bit). Tried to follow https://forums.adobe.com/message/6338142, but can't find a download for Flash Player 13.0 debugger version for Windows 7. The Windows 8 file named Windows8.1-KB2867622-x64.msu won't install.

I guess I'm either missing something obvious or there's no such thing as Flash Player 13.0 debugger for Windows 7 64 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html:

> Adobe Flash Player 14 (Win and Mac) and 11.2 (Linux) - 32 bit and 64
>   bit debugger (aka debug player or content debuggers) and standalone
>   (aka projectors) players for Flex and Flash developers.

So, now that we're on 14 and not 13 I guess you want to click on the 'Projector' link http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/14/flashplayer_14_sa.exe or http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/14/flashplayer_14_sa_debug.exe for the debug version.

I don't know where you need to put this file or in fact how you get Flash Builder 4.7 or Flash CC to use the updated player.

/* EDIT */
On windows for Flash Builder 4.7 (I know you asked for Flash CC, but it seems from your question that getting it to work after downloading wasn't the problem you were facing; others using Flash Builder will find it tricky to update the player)... change directory to:

> C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 (64 Bit)\player\win

Add a directory with the same name as the version you're adding:

> 14.0

Place the newly downloaded file, renaming it like so:

> FlashPlayerDebugger.exe

i esta!